# 2-2-2 SEU cable for sub panel

Tags: subpanel, conduit

I have approximately 100ft of 2-2-2 copper SEU cable laying around on a spool. I am looking at putting a 100 amp sub panel in my garage. The new run will be about 40ft so I am wondering if I am able to use this cable and add a single ground cable. Or is it permitted to remove the outer sheathing of the SEU cable and get my 4 conductors that way. (Or at least my three (3) #2 conductors and I can buy a ground wire)
Plan would be to run in 2” pvc conduit that I also have laying around. All work is indoors and garage is attached, so everything is within the same structure.
Trying to figure out if I can use up this miscellaneous material.

Comment: Trade it on Craigslist for what you need.

Comment: Can you remove the sheath from 1 foot of the cable to see whether the wires are marked (use them) or not (sell them and get new wire)?

Answer (score 2):

First, it's always a bad idea to misapply wires you already own, especially when you own very valuable copper and can easily use very inexpensive aluminum.  Flip this stuff on Craigslist to someone who needs what you got and doesn't like aluminum. #2 Cu SEU is 115A wire and is legal on 125A services, or 115A feeders (breakered at 125A since 115A breakers are not made).

### Using the SEU cable

Shucking the SEU wires won't work as the interior wires are not individually marked.

You are not allowed to run neutral in a separate cable from the other conductors.  They must be together.  The bare wire in SEU is neutral.  It is not ground, however it's allowed to be reassigned to ground if neutral is handled or not needed.

Note also that SEU is *not* permitted underground - not even inside conduit.

If the entire route is in conduit, you could run a ground wire separately *(or better: use EMT, IMC or RMC conduit **which is the ground**; in that case SEU is quite correct!)* The conduit must be assembled complete before any wires are pulled in, so you'd need relatively large conduit with access points as needed for an easy pull. SEU is stiff stuff, but you know that.

### What we would otherwise recommend

We generally recommend: first rethink your sizing. Do you really need 100A or did you just pick it because it's a nice round number.  If 90A will suffice, there's a bargain cable out there called #2 aluminum - at a pricing sweet spot because of wide use in 100A services. (feeders require larger wire).

But if you want 100A, that's fine, that can happen at #1 aluminum, or #3 copper. As you probably know, this must be 4-wire cable, or as I said, non-flex metal conduit the whole way.

### A few extra notes

First, if this is related to EV charging, freeze [and watch this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iyp_X3mwE1w&t=1695s). You need far less power than most people think.  Alec underplays **Power Sharing** which is incredibly powerful when you have multiple EVs.  if you had 4 cars that need 15, 30, 55 and 250 miles respectively: they'll all finish by morning sharing ONE 50A circuit. Really.  And they'll do it automatically, assuming they each have their own EVSE and they are networking.

And Tesla will cheerfully sell you *today* a mix of Tesla and non-Tesla (J1772) EVSEs that network like that, cheaper than any other unit in town.

There is nothing wrong with aluminum wire at these large sizes; it is proven reliable. What people think will happen with aluminum will actually happen with copper if you fail to use a torque wrench.

Whatever you do, make sure you have done a NEC Article 220 Load Calculation on the loads on your service, and affirm that your panel can support these loads.  See how helpful it is that most people only need 20A/240V for EV charging? (about 3 times the speed of level 1 charging).

Comment: 100amp was just a generic size based on what materials I have around. This would be for a 50amp EV outlet and I wanted to give myself some room for future. 90 amp is definitely feasible. 
Not opposed to trying to sell the copper and using aluminum if it makes sense. 
 Is 2-2-2-4 Aluminum SER cable what you’re talking about for the 90amp?  Is conduit still required?

Comment: @Waypastmidnight Yeah, that sounds great.  For the EV think about hard-wiring a wall unit such as [this unit for non-Teslas](https://shop.tesla.com/product/j1772-wall-connector). It sidesteps the need for a [costly socket](https://youtu.be/HzcBZUPZXqA) and in most NEC 2020 states, a $150 GFCI breaker.  (heck at that point you're halfway to the wall unit lol).  The linked EVSE supports Power Sharing for the happy day a second EV arrives.

Comment: It looks like the wires in the OP's SEU cable *are* individually marked

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this:

- The wires must be individually usable as is. With NM cable, that is generally not the case. However, I checked and at least with Southwire copper SEU cable, that is OK. The [specifications](https://assets.southwire.com/ImConvServlet/imconv/29eb61d214155f6967f8be2c0fd9b8614a3b20bc/origin?hybrisId=otmmHybrisPRD&assetDescr=Copper%20Service%20Entrance%20%28SE%29%20Cable.spec) say:

> Individual Conductors Rated XHHW-2 or THHN/THWN.

which is exactly what you want. But you need to **make sure that they are actually marked** that way or else you may fail inspection. Remove the sheath from a couple of feet and see what the markings show.

- You will need to mark one of the wires green at each place the wire is accessible (which is likely just the ends) to use it as a ground. That is only allowed with 4 AWG or larger, but since you have 2 AWG wires, that's OK.

---

**Update:** Based on a comment, the individual wires are:

*AWG 2 CU TYPE XHHW-2 600 VOLT and bare copper neutral.*

so you *can* use the individual insulated wires for hot or neutral, marking with white tape at each visible location for the neutral wire. 2" PVC is plenty big enough.

Comment: I seriously doubt the conductors are marked correctly

Comment: Rated and marked are two different things, and they must be **marked** if the jacket is being removed. I have yet to find a cable that is so constructed.

Comment: The outer sheathing is marked:
AWG 2 CU TYPE SE CABLE STYLE U
TYPE XHHW-2 600 VOLT

Inside there are a black and black/red cable.
Each are marked:
AWG 2 CU TYPE XHHW-2 600 VOLT

and bare copper neutral.